# Does std::wstring support UTF-16 and UTF-32 on Windows?

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8, utf-16, utf-32

I'm learning about Unicode and have a few questions that I'm hoping to get answered.

1) I've read that on Linux, a **std::wstring** is 4-bytes, while on Windows, it's 2-bytes.  Does this mean that Linux internal support is **UTF-32** while Windows it is **UTF-16**?

2) Is the use of std::wstring very similar to the std::string interface?

3) Does VC++ offer support for using a 4-byte std::wstring?

4) Do you have to change compiler options if you use std::wstring?

As a sidenote, I came across a string library for working with UTF-8 which has a very similar interface to std::string which provides familiar functionality such as length, substr, find, upper/lower case conversion etc.  The library is **Glib::ustring**.

Please feel free to add any comments or additional advice, because I really need it.

Thank you!

Comment: The C++11 char32_t type should provide a solution, it is however dead last on the Microsoft to-do list.  Pretty doubtful that it will get any use in the next 10 years :)  Yes, you almost always need a library to do anything non-trivial.  ICU is a common choice.

Comment: @HansPassant, this was causing me quite a bit of VC++ confusion with undeclared identifiers and such.  ICU is so big...I think that I'm going to try Glib::ustring to see if it satisfies all of my needs.  BTW, a while back you warned me about codepages and you were so right.

Comment: Pretty much everything about it is written in utf8everywhere.org manifesto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) `wstring` is a `basic_string<wchar_t>` and the size of `wchar_t` is implementation dependent and encoding agnostic (the standard just says that "*its values can represent distinct codes for all members of the largest extended character set specified among the supported locales*".  But yes, an implementation that has `sizeof(wchar_t)=4` bytes supports UTF-32, and `sizeof(wchar_t)=2` bytes supports UTF-16.

2) `wstring` is a `basic_string<wchar_t>` whereas `string` is a `basic_string<char>`, so yes, it is a very similar interface. You will have to use `wcout`, `wcin` and `wfstream` though, and have some other constraints like this.

3) No, MSVC defines `wchar_t` as [unsigned short](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc953fe1.aspx), which defines and limits `wstring` as you said.  MSVC gives possibility of handling `wchar_t` as a typedef instead of an internal type.  You could imagine then to redefine the typedef, but I suspect this is extreamly risky and evil.

4) No, it's up to you to choose to the string type you want.

5) UTF-32 and the standard :  Interestingly, in the very encoding agnostic C++ standard, UTF-32 is mentionned explicitely only for `codecvt`:  "*the specialization codecvt `<char32_t, char, mbstate_t>` converts between the UTF-32 and UTF-8 encoding forms. codecvt converts between the native character sets for narrow and wide characters.*"  This suggests that `char32_t` would be the portable approach to UTF-32.  Unfortunately MSVC doesn't support this type yet.

Comment: At Christophe and @RemyLebeau, thank you for the excellent answers.

Comment: "MSVC defines wchar_t as unsigned short" By default, `wchar_t` is a builtin type. The page you linked to explains that.

Comment: @DDrmmr, yes, my wording is misleading.  Of course, with the default options of the compiler, MSVC handles wchar_t as a native type.  What I meant was that the MSVC impelmentation --whatever the option-- gives this  type the same caracteristics/limits as an unsigned short.

Answer (score 7):

> 1) I've read that on Linux, a std::wstring is 4-bytes, while on Windows, it's 2-bytes. Does this mean that Linux internal support is UTF-32 while Windows it is UTF-16?

It is actually `wchar_t`, not `std::wstring`, that is 4 bytes on Linux and 2 bytes on Windows.  `std::wstring` is a typedef for `std::basic_string<wchar_t>`, so `std::wstring` supports UTF-32 on Linux and UTF-16 on Windows, yes.

> 2) Is the use of std::wstring very similar to the std::string interface?

Both `std::wstring` and `std::string` are typedefs of `std:basic_string`, so they have the same interface, just different `value_type` types (`wchar_t` vs `char`, respectively).

> 3) Does VC++ offer support for using a 4-byte std::wstring?

Not for `std::wstring` itself, no.  But you can create your own `std::basic_string` typedef, eg:

```
typedef std::basic_string<int32_t> u32string;
```

In fact, this is exactly how the new C++11 `std::u16string` and `std::u32string` types are defined:

```
typedef std::basic_string<char16_t> u16string;
typedef std::basic_string<char32_t> u32string;
```

It is also not unheard of to make a typedef of `std::basic_string` for `TCHAR`:

```
typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;
```

> As a sidenote, I came across a string library for working with UTF-8 which has a very similar interface to std::string which provides familiar functionality such as length, substr, find, upper/lower case conversion etc. The library is Glib::ustring.

Technically speaking, you can (and many people do) use a standard `std::string` for UTF-8.  `Glib::ustring` just takes it further by using `gunichar` (a typedef for `guint32`) instead of `char`, and exposes its interfaces to operate in terms of raw Unicode codepoints instead of encoded codeunits.