# How to read a UTF-16 text file in C++17

Tags: c++, visual-c++, unicode, c++17, utf-16

I am very new to C++. I want to read a UTF-16 text file in C++17 in Visual Studio 2019.

I have tried several methods in the internet (including StackOverflow) but none of them worked, and some of them didn't compile (I think they only support older compilers).

**I am trying to achieve this without using any 3rd party libraries.**

This reads a text file, but it has some weird characters and spaces between each letter.

```
// open file for reading
std::wifstream istrm(filename, std::ios::binary);
if (!istrm.is_open()) {
    std::cout << "failed to open " << filename << '\n';
}
else {
    std::wstring s;
    std::getline(istrm, s);
    std::wcout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Then I found some solutions for this using the following libraries

```
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>

// open file for reading
std::wifstream istrm(filename, std::ios::binary);
istrm.imbue(std::locale(istrm.getloc(), new std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t, 0x10ffff, std::consume_header>));
if (!istrm.is_open()) {
    std::cout << "failed to open " << filename << '\n';
}
else {
    std::wstring s;
    std::getline(istrm, s);
    std::wcout << s << std::endl;
}
```

This time it didn't even compile, got the following errors at the `std::codecvt_utf16` line:

> Error C4996    'std::codecvt_utf16': warning STL4017: std::wbuffer_convert, std::wstring_convert, and the  header (containing std::codecvt_mode, std::codecvt_utf8, std::codecvt_utf16, and std::codecvt_utf8_utf16) are deprecated in C++17. (The std::codecvt class template is NOT deprecated.) The C++ Standard doesn't provide equivalent non-deprecated functionality; consider using MultiByteToWideChar() and WideCharToMultiByte() from  instead. You can define _SILENCE_CXX17_CODECVT_HEADER_DEPRECATION_WARNING or _SILENCE_ALL_CXX17_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS to acknowledge that you have received this warning.

I would appreciate if someone can provide a solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Get an external Unicode library.

Comment: So there is no way to do this without using any 3rd party library?

Comment: The Standard Library isn't really mature enough yet to properly handle Unicode. Furthermore, the entire `<codecvt>` header was deprecated in C++17.

Comment: I see, so what are the alternatives may I
 ask?

Comment: You may use ICU library: http://site.icu-project.org/home

Comment: You could write the code yourself. Decoding UTF-16 isn't all that difficult. Just steal some code off of github ;)

Comment: @P.PICARD thanks for your inputs, I'll try that.

Comment: @DeiDei thanks for your input, I will try to find some good code on GitHub :)

Comment: just out of curiosity, if I try and get a normal `char*(std::string)` from the UTF-16 text file(which has weird characters and spaces) and if I convert this `std::string`
 to `char16_t*` will I get the correct output?

Comment: The entire library was not deprecated.  The standard library is completely sufficient to do what you want.  Someone will post an answer in due time, don't give up! :)

Comment: @cyberbisson ok, thank you for you input as well. :)

Comment: Please post the compilation error for those of us that don't have Visual Studio.

Comment: probably a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103925/how-well-is-unicode-supported-in-c11

Comment: @cyberbisson I've added the error as well, it says to use `MultiByteToWideChar() ` which I've tried following a tutorial, but couldn't get it to work.(I am very new to C++)

Comment: It is not an error.  It is going to show this *warning* for at least another decade, such are the benefits of using a C++ compiler with an 1-800 support phone number.  So simply #define _SILENCE_CXX17_CODECVT_HEADER_DEPRECATION_WARNING to move on with your life.

Comment: On Windows, you don't need to do any encoding conversion, nor any external library for this task. Create a `std::ifstream` in binary mode, then simply read the whole file into `std::wstring` and be done with it. Assuming you want to read `UTF-16 LE` only. For `UTF-16 BE` (rarely used on Windows) you need to swap every 2nd byte.

Comment: I see, my text file seems to be `UTF-16 BE` that's maybe why there is an
 extra space between every letter and the first letter is a square

Comment: The 1st "letter" you are seeing propably is the [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). You can use it to distinguish between UTF-16 LE/BE.

Comment: Microsoft's [fopen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen?view=vs-2019) can be used to read UTF-encoded files as well; e.g. `fopen("newfile.txt", "rt+, ccs=UTF-16LE")`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, read related questions like [Does std::wstring support UTF-16 and UTF-32 on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25938373/does-stdwstring-support-utf-16-and-utf-32-on-windows) and [Is 16-bit wchar_t formally valid for representing full Unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39548465/is-16-bit-wchar-t-formally-valid-for-representing-full-unicode).

If what you want is simply read/write strings as a blob for which you already know the encoding is UTF-16, without performing any conversion or manipulation, and you are in an environment like Visual Studio 2019 on Windows for which [`wchar_t` is intended to hold UTF-16](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/learnwin32/working-with-strings), then you can use the C++ wide strings and streams.

Now, if you need to perform conversions, support several encodings, iterate within strings (for some definitions of iterate), or in general anything non-trivial, you are out of luck at the moment if you want to stay within C++17. The C++ Standard committee has established a working group for Unicode, so expect to see *some* improvements in this area in the upcoming years. For the moment, you will need to use either Win32 functions like `MultiByteToWideChar` and `WideCharToMultiByte`, or an external library like International Components for Unicode (ICU) or Boost's Locale.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, I'll try the `MultiByteToWideChar` and `WideCharToMultiByte` approach again and see, I tried it earlier, I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @LukeWilliam You're welcome! They are not hard to use -- if you have trouble, please open another question with the code that fails and we can take a look :-) Typically, you will want to call `MultiByteToWideChar`/`WideCharToMultiByte` functions twice: first you find out the final length after conversion, then you allocate memory for it, and then you call it again to write the actual result into the buffer.

Comment: “expect to see *some* improvements in this area in the upcoming years” It’s almost 5 years later now and there doesn’t seem to be anything. I’m gladly corrected on this statement.